# Tree-shakeable strategy pattern in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack

I have been trying to build a library that requires its consumers to use a specific strategy per target. My current architecture follows:

[Application] -> contains -> [player] -> contains -> [renderer]

Currently, `Renderer` is an interface which needs to be replaced for different platforms:

- Mobile -> uses MobileRenderer
- Web -> uses WebRenderer

I have the freedom to use any bundlers - currently using Webpack for the app and Rollup for the lib - and what I could achieve follows:

My lib exports a `Player` interface and a `createPlayer` function which returns a `PlayerInterface`. Then, on the application side I have a Webpack alias that resolves the correct platform library based on a build input.

e.g:

```
import { createPlayer } from "my-lib";


const player = createPlayer()
```

Then we build the application with

```
npm run build --platform=web
```

to which webpack will transform the `my-lib` import into `my-lib/platforms/web`, which also contains an exported `createPlayer` function which uses the correct renderer.

My question is the, from the application's point of view, how can we make sure that we import the correct renderer per platform on build time while allowing tree-shaking (so only including the correct sources)? I find that using the build system to do that is quite obscure, as it doesn't leave a clear trace of what's going on.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Best,

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options. I'd recommend against having a compile-time switch, since that requires you to distribute multiple copies of your library (which isn't idiomatic). However, if you *really* wanted to do this, I'd suggest using webpack's `ProvidePlugin` or `resolve.alias` config field to dynamically link your code to the appropriate renderer at build time.

A more pragmatic approach, in my opinion, would be to have two entry points to your application, and allow the implementor to choose which entry point to use. This is similar to how `react-dom` switches between browser rendering and server rendering (i.e., `react-dom` versus `react-dom/server`):

```
// index.js

export * from './shared';
export {default as renderer} from './renderers/web';
```

```
// mobile/index.js

export * from '../shared';
export {default as renderer} from '../renderers/mobile';
```

Then, someone using your library could `import {renderer, foo} from 'your-lib'` or `import {renderer, foo} from 'your-lib/mobile'`.

Both of the above approaches work at build time.

While the latter approach normally forces you to choose which version of the library to use in your code, you can use webpack's `resolve.alias` configuration field to force imports to `your-lib` be redirected to `your-lib/mobile`.

Comment: Hi @mattbasta, thanks for your answer! Your webpack `resolve.alias` approach is what we are doing already. We already have different entrypoints which conform to the same interface and on the application side we make Webpack select the correct entry and that works fine. The problem with this approach is that is not very clear how things work.

Sorry if my question was not clear, but I'm looking to an alternative to your suggestion.